# Issues with creating dynamic INI files in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to make some dynamically made INI files for some GPRS printers. I have the original INI file here and wish to use PHP to make bulk copies of the file with certain changes per printer. I can push the updated INI file to them direct but I am having issues getting the formatting of the INI file right. I have a text file just now with all the settings. I am using this code as a proof of concept but what happens is that it removed all spaces and all line brakes causing it not to work! Is there anyway of getting this to work? Creating an array for all the data (We are talking 75 sections of data. Not all will change per printer mind.)

This is my code:

```
    $replace = array("ID"=>"AC001");

    $inifile = 'ini.txt';

    $fh = fopen($inifile, 'r');
    $inifile = fread($fh, filesize($inifile));
    fclose($fh);

    foreach($replace as $key => $value)
    {
        $template = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $value, $inifile);
    }

    echo $template;

    $filename = $replace["ID"].".ini";

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'x+');
    fwrite($handle, $template);
    fclose($handle);

Data format:

    [section number (1-75)]
    Name=Parm name
    NameEn=Parm name
    Command= Parm (demo case: {$id})
    IsValid=1
    DataMode=1
    IsHide=1
    [section number (1-75)]
    Name=Parm name
    NameEn=Parm name
    Command= Parm
    IsValid=1
    DataMode=1
    IsHide=1
```

What comes out the other side is just one big long line of text.

OK came up with a better option that works! Just now that its broken the string replace function!

```
function arr2ini(array $a, array $parent = array())
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            //subsection case
            //merge all the sections into one array...
            $sec = array_merge((array) $parent, (array) $k);
            //add section information to the output
            $out .= '[' . join('.', $sec) . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            //recursively traverse deeper
            $out .= arr2ini($v, $sec);
        }
        else
        {
            //plain key->value case
            $out .= "$k=$v" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

$replace = array("ID"=>"AC001");

$inifile = 'ini.ini';

$files = parse_ini_file("$inifile",true);


foreach($replace as $key => $value)
{
    echo $template = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $value, $files);
}

var_dump($template);

$filename = $replace["ID"].".ini";

$ini = arr ; 2ini($template);

echo $ini;

$handle = fopen($filename, 'x+');
fwrite($handle, $ini);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I have tested your code and its working fine for me

Comment: The code works fine, its the formatting of the outputted INI file that is the issue. I need each thing to be on a line of its own and not as one huge long string.

Comment: If you want to have your file's content written on seperate lines, add `"\n"` somewhere in your code; *where,* I don't know. I couldn't test this properly, but `"\n"` is what you need; that I know for sure.

Comment: Nope! Just added them into the line as a character!

Comment: Inserted where exactly? Its location is crucial. Plus, it must be `"\n"` and not `'\n'` just in case that's what you did.

Comment: I added them to the document template ini.txt.

Comment: Just to test, replace `echo $template;` with `echo $template . "\n";` see what type of output you get. Btw, you'd need to concatenate it in your template using `. "\n"` see if that will make it work. This is not our usual "write each value to file and add \n to each".

Comment: I have a solution but its created another issue! See the first posts for more info!

Comment: Regarding your now deleted question about printers: what was your actual question? How to reduce the number of rows generated? 1200/hour isn't a lot for a relational database. If you find that your database starts to slow down, you can always move live rows to an archive table - presumably you don't need this data right back to the first half hour of operation.

Comment: Well the reason I was asking is there any better ways of doing this? If I have a 100 of these things adding 600 entries per hour each by the end of the day Im going have just under 1.5 million rows! That is just insane. Also makes working with the data just horrible! The data i hope to keep for as long as possible (3 months min?)

Comment: (Don't forget to use @halfer (or whatever) to notify people of responses). I've no idea what data they are generating, but if you need it, then you need it. Create your 1.5M rows/day and archive regularly. Throw away data you don't need, of course. You could consider a NoSQL solution as well - they dispense with a lot of relational overhead and so might be faster.